Other than to Zoe Washington, has 47 ever lied in the World of Assassination trilogy?
Other than to Zoe Washington, has 47 ever lied in the World of Assassination trilogy?
One thing I've noticed is that 47 doesn't lie. Has there been a point where he did tell someone a lie?

Depends on what exactly you consider lying, since 47 is good at being ambiguous. One possible example is the IAGO auction in Showstopper where 47 introduces himself as Tobias Reaper (I thought it was Rieper?), a friend of Viktor's. I think it is fair to say that that is not his real name, and that he is not a friend of Viktor's.

I mean his name is indeed Tobias Reaper, but Vikor isn't his friend

@Dave What makes you say that it is indeed his name? Digging around, this wiki lists it as a cover identity, along with Byrd, Metzger, Jacob Leiter and Dr. Cropes. In this Hitman 2 mission he states that he is not using the name anymore. I've never seen any indications that he has a canonical name beyond 47.

I never heard him use anything other than Tobias Reaper, as of WoA his name is Tobias Reaper

@Dave Hmm, I would definitely call it a fake identity. In "The Farewell", Tobias Rieper is referred to as a half-assed sock puppet identity, in Showstopper Dahlia runs a BG check on Rieper and concludes it is a fake identity. In the prologue he takes the name 47 when asked by Diana, who also only refers to him as 47. Also makes sense to not use his real name when working as an assassin.
